# NSTouchBar integration not calling

Tags: swift, macos, delegates, nswindow, nstouchbar

I am integrating TouchBar support to my App. I used the how to from Rey Wenderlich and implemented everything as follows:

If `self.touchBarArray`got filled the `makeTouchBar()` Method returns the NSTouchBar object. If I print out some tests the `identifiers` object is filled and works.

What not work is that the `makeItemForIdentifier` method not get triggered. So the items do not get created and the TouchBar is still empty.

**Strange behavior:** If I add `print(touchBar)` and a Breakpoint before returning the NSTouchBar object it works and the TouchBar get presented as it should (also the `makeItemForIdentifier` function gets triggered). Even if it disappears after some seconds... also strange.

```
@available(OSX 10.12.2, *)
extension ViewController: NSTouchBarDelegate {
    override func makeTouchBar() -> NSTouchBar? {
        if(self.touchBarArray.count != 0) {
            let touchBar = NSTouchBar()
            touchBar.delegate = self
            touchBar.customizationIdentifier = NSTouchBarCustomizationIdentifier("com.TaskControl.ViewController.WorkspaceBar")
            var identifiers: [NSTouchBarItemIdentifier] = []
            for (workspaceId, _) in self.touchBarArray {
                identifiers.append(NSTouchBarItemIdentifier("com.TaskControl.ViewController.WorkspaceBar.\(workspaceId)"))
            }
            touchBar.defaultItemIdentifiers = identifiers
            touchBar.customizationAllowedItemIdentifiers = identifiers
            return touchBar
        }
        return nil
    }

    func touchBar(_ touchBar: NSTouchBar, makeItemForIdentifier identifier: NSTouchBarItemIdentifier) -> NSTouchBarItem? {
        if(self.touchBarArray.count != 0) {
            for (workspaceId, data) in self.touchBarArray {
                if(identifier == NSTouchBarItemIdentifier("com.TaskControl.ViewController.WorkspaceBar.\(workspaceId)")) {
                        let saveItem = NSCustomTouchBarItem(identifier: identifier)
                        let button = NSButton(title: data["name"] as! String, target: self, action: #selector(self.touchBarPressed))
                        button.bezelColor = NSColor(red:0.35, green:0.61, blue:0.35, alpha:1.00)
                        saveItem.view = button
                        return saveItem
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show how your class is declared?  What is this class a subclass of?  Do you have it conforming to `NSTouchBarDelegate`?

Comment: Yes, it do. Updated my question.

Comment: Please post a [mre], including all code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which view is first responder?

Comment: Thanks! `self.view.window?.makeFirstResponder(self)` in `viewDidLoad()` did help. Thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 1):

`self.view.window?.makeFirstResponder(self)` in `viewDidLoad()` did solve the problem.